# Add columns but keep a specific id

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "Listing" that looks like this:

```
| listing_id |                   amenities                      |
|------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|  5629709   | {"Air conditioning",Heating, Essentials,Shampoo} |
|  4156372   |   {"Wireless Internet",Kitchen,"Pets allowed"}   |
```

And another table "Amenity" like this:

```
| amenity_id |                     amenities                    |
|------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|      1     |                 Air conditioning                 |
|      2     |                      Kitchen                     |
|      3     |                      Heating                     |
```

Is there a way to join the two tables in a new one "Listing_Amenity" like this:

```
| listing_id | amenities |
|------------|-----------|
|  5629709   |     1     |
|  5629709   |     3     |
|  4156372   |     2     |
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use unnest:

```
CREATE TABLE Listing_Amenity
AS
SELECT l.listing_id, a.amenity_id
FROM Listing l
, unnest(l.ammenities) sub(elem)
JOIN Amenity a
  ON a.ammenities = sub.elem;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=66f73fe607e443ec7cc7cacaae71aaac)**

Comment: Is this creating the last table "Listing_Amenity" ? Because the other two already exists

Comment: @vkatsou You could use Create table AS to achieve it

Comment: Is there any other way besides unnest function? like SELECT regexp_split_to_table(amenities, ',') amenities

Comment: yes, you could use splt_to_table as well if your "amenities" is not an array but simple string

Comment: CREATE TABLE Listing_Amenity
AS
SELECT l.listing_id, a.amenity_id
FROM Listing l
,  regexp_split_to_table(amenities, ',') amenities
JOIN Amenity a
  ON a.ammenities = amenities; Wright?